# How ibatis data mapper calculates whether SQL command is completed

Tags: c#, oracle, orm, ibatis, ibatis.net

I wanted to know how ibatis take notification from the SQL connection that a task is completed.
For eg 
There is one insert statement executed through C# data object so how Ibatis come to know that all data is being inserted.